# In jmeter I need to send a file path with random file name, how to get that random file name to pass in a request

Tags: web-services, jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing, webrequest

I am load testing a web application scenario in which:

1.) First I need to upload an `excel` file it will be parsed and sheets (tabs in excel) loads into a drop-down.

2.)Then selects an option in drop-down and clicks on import button.

3.) After clicking on import a new pop up open with some data loaded in the grid with "update to database" button. Now clicked on the update to database button.

This is my scenario of load test here I need to load test "import" and "update to database" requests

In this scenario 4 requests works.

- **In point 1**: servicename url is: /xxx/xxx/uploadLoader.aspx

**in params are:** 2 viewstates, button, appuser, company, filename (with multi-part data)

**response:** it returns HTML of file upload control

- **Point 2 using 2 requests:**

**a)** service url is:  /xxxx/xxxx.asmx/updateImportSubTableFormat

**in params:**

```
{"as_connstring":["GET"],"alist_import":[{"__type":"ApplecartDS.DataLib.ImportTableMain","rowstate":"OLD","tableno":"019","oldtableno":"019","formatid":"I0000012","oldformatid":"I0000012","columnname":"pay_billrefno","oldcolumnname":"","columndesc":"Bill No","aormdesc":"Actual","excelcolumnname":"D","excelcolumnno":"3","excelcolumnnameadd1":"","excelcolumnnoadd1":-1,"excelcolumnnameadd2":"","excelcolumnnoadd2":-1,"serialno":"1","oldserialno":2,"formatname":"","startingrowno":0,"endingrowno":0,"keycolumn":"","keycolumndesc":"","payiddesc":null,"attributetype":"","paytype":"A",".............**some more output data here**.................... 1,"excelcolumnnameadd2":"","excelcolumnnoadd2":-1,"serialno":"3","oldserialno":3,"formatname":"","startingrowno":0,"endingrowno":0,"keycolumn":"","keycolumndesc":"","payiddesc":null,"attributetype":"","paytype":"A",""provision_actual":"P","dsexecstatus":"","dsmsg":"","slno":0,"as_fromatid":"I0000012","ai_xlcolumnname":"A","ai_xlcolumnno":"1","ai_startrow":"2","ai_endrow":0,"ai_header":"1","as_payid":"MEDRE","as_leaveid":"MEDRE","as_wfdcolname":"","ai_wfdcolno":0,"as_arrcolname":"","ai_arrcolno":0,"as_transafertype":"A"}
```

**response:**

```
{"d":[{"__type":"ApplecartDS.DataLib.ImportTableMain","rowstate":"OLD","tableno":"","oldtableno":"","formatid":"","oldformatid":"","columnname":"","oldcolumnname":"","columndesc":"","aormdesc":"","excelcolumnname":"","excelcolumnno":0,"excelcolumnnameadd1":"","excelcolumnnoadd1":-1,"excelcolumnnameadd2":"","excelcolumnnoadd2":-1,"serialno":0,"oldserialno":0,"formatname":"","startingrowno":0,"endingrowno":0,.............**some more output data here**...................."","valuefrom":"E","default_value":"","aorm":"A","benefitsid":"","licpayid":"","createmaster":"","allowzero":"N","groupid":"","groupdesc":"","reimbpayid":"","provision_actual":"P","dsexecstatus":"","dsmsg":"","slno":0}]}
```

**Note:** If I hit same request wit same in parmas then it returns correct same response.

**b)** service url is: /AAA/AAA.asmx/importXLData

**in params:**

```
{"as_connstring":["GET"],"as_filename":"C:\\Websites\\xxxx\\xxxx\\admin\\001\\admin115.248.100.6825520164659134Import_Template.xlsx","ai_header":2,"as_tablename":"rm_claimsmain","as_sheetname":"'Reim claim$'","as_tableno":"019","as_fromatid":"I0000012","as_creditperiodid":"","isUpdate":false,"isupdatemonattribute":false,"alistUpdatedata":[],"as_excelfilepath":"C:\\Websites\\xxxx\\xxxx\\admin\\001\\admin115.248.100.6825520164659134Import_Template.xlsx"}
```

**response**

```
{"d":[{"__type":"ApplecartDS.DataLib.ExcelDataImport","CValues1":"","CValues2":"","CValues3":"","CValues4":"","CValues5":"","CValues6":"","CValues7":"","CValues8":"",..........**very long out put data here**.......
,"NValues50":0,"NValues51":0,3":0,"IValues4":0,"rowmodify":"N","rowstate":"OLD","dsexecstatus":null,"dsmsg":""}]}
```

**Note:** But if I hit the same request again then it displays response as below that are different from above response (first-time response). Because the file name changes every time in case of the manual but I am not able to get the new file name to pass it in `JMeter` request.

**second-time response:**

```
{"d":[{"__type":"ApplecartDS.DataLib.ExcelDataImport","CValues1":"","CValues2":"","CValues3":"","CValues4":"","CValues5":"","CVal","CValues17":"","CValues18":"","CValues19":................................. dsexecstatus":"FAIL","dsmsg":"Exception : System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException (0x80004005): The Microsoft Office Access database engine could not find the object \u0027C:\\xxxx\\xxxx\\xxx\\admin\\001\\admin115.248.100.6825520165121629Import_Template_test_case_9May2016.xlsx\u0027.  Make sure the object exists and that you spell its name and the path name correctly.
```

**point 3 is using 1 request**

service url: /xxxx/xxxx.asmx/importXLData

**in params**

```
{"as_connstring":["GET"],"as_filename":"C:\\xxxx\\xxxx\\temp\\admin\\001\\admin115.248.100.682552016571324rm_claimsmain.xml;C:\\Websites\\cPayv8html\\temp\\admin\\001\\admin115.248.100.682552016571324rm_cliams.xml","ai_header":"1","as_tablename":"rm_claimsmain","as_sheetname":"'Reim claim$'","as_tableno":"019","as_fromatid":"I0000012","as_creditperiodid":"","isUpdate":true,"isupdatemonattribute":false,"alistUpdatedata":[{"__type":"ApplecartDS.DataLib.ExcelDataImport","CValues1":"Employee No;C;30;em_empno","CValues2":"Bill No;C;30;","CValues3":"Bill Date;D;30;","CVal/Date(-62135596800000)\/"..........**some more in data**..........,"DValues10":"\/Date(-62135596800000)\/","ls_msg1":"5","ls_msg2":"C:\\xxxx\\xxxx\\xx\\admin\\001\\admin115.248.100.682552016571324rm_claimsmain.xml;C:\\xxxx\\xxx\\xx\\admin\\001\\admin115.248.100.682552016571324rm_cliams.xml","ls_msg3":"","ls_msg4":"","NValues1":0,"NV4":0,"rowmodify":"N","rowstate":"OLD","dsexecstatus":null,"dsmsg":""}],"as_excelfilepath":"C:\\xxxx\\xxxx\\xxx\\admin\\001\\admin115.248.100.6825520164659134Import_Template_test_case_9May2016.xlsx"}
```

**response**

```
{"d":[{"__type":"ApplecartDS.DataLib.ExcelDataImport","CValues1":"","CValues2":"","CValues3":"","CValues4":"","CValues5":"","CValues6":"","CValues7":"","CValues8":"","CValues9":"","CValues10":"","CValues11":"","CValues12":"","CValues13":"","CValues14":"","CValues15":"","CValues16":"","CValues17":"","CValues18":"","................................ "rowmodify":"N","rowstate":"OLD","dsexecstatus":"SUCCESS","dsmsg":"Update to Database success !    New Rows added :0 \u003c\u003e Rows Updated : 49"}]}
```

If I hit same request again then second time response is:

```
......................"dsexecstatus":"FAIL","dsmsg":"Exception : Could not find file \u0027C:\\Websites\\cPayv8html\\temp\\admin\\001\\admin115.248.100.682552016525264rm_claimsmain.xml\u0027."}]}
```

My issue is in second-time response it is not showing correct response as the file name is changing randomly and I am not able to trace it to pass changed file path to the request.

Is there any way to handle it?  Please help me out, how can I load test it with an authentic response.

Comment: Please do not ask several things in one question. Please do not give lots of unnecessary detail. To answer this question we would need to read the whole text and work out which bits need to be ignored. Please read [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

${__RandomString(6,a12zeczclk, MYVAR)}
will return a random string of 6 characters picked from a12zeczclk set and store the result in MYVAR, MYVAR will contain string like 2z22ak or z11kce, …

see:
http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__RandomString

Comment: But this can not resolve my issue because, Web server generating a random number that is added in file name, and sending as a parameter. So if I generate random number using above function it is not sure that my function will generate same random number that is added in file name by web server, they will never match possibly.

Comment: Would you please clear this .. You are mentioning Server will generate a random number and that you want refer in another request?

Comment: Referring application as server. I upload a file in A request now hits B request in which file name is going as a parameter with complete file path but with changed file name adding some random number. Here I am not able to trace that changed file name that is generated by adding some random number. Now I hit C request in which an XML file going as parameter by changing its name as excel (it is the same XLS file that is converted in XML to use in C request.). So my problem is that I am not able to send same file name as it is required in the request, as the name randomly getting changed.

Answer (score 0):

Looking into

> Could not find file \u0027C:\Websites\cPayv8html\temp\admin\001\admin115.248.100.682552016525264rm_claimsmain.xml\u0027.

It seems that when you upload the file, it's being stored somewhere in a temporary location and when the file is imported into the database - it's deleted. So it's classic "correlation" example where you need to get a dynamic parameter from previous response and add it to the next request.

I would suggest carefully inspect server responses and to get the temporary filename from there.

As your server responds with JSON I would suggest to use

- [JSON Path PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Path_PostProcessor) - if you're using JMeter 3.0
- [JSON Path Extractor](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JSONPathExtractor/) - if you're sitting on a previous JMeter version

JSON Path Syntax is very easy, check the following references:

- [JSONPath - XPath for JSON](http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/)
- [JSONPath Online Evaluator](http://jsonpath.com/)
- [Advanced Usage of the JSON Path Extractor in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/advanced-usage-json-path-extractor-jmeter)